# WordPress Multisite: Redirect users to the their site admin panel after successful login

Tags: wordpress, redirect, cookies, wordpress-rest-api, multisite

This function is to build a login-free admin access of users to the site they belong to. However, I am receiving "Too many redirects" error message.

```
add_action('wp_authenticate', 'custom_login');

function custom_login(){ 
 
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = 'test';
$creds['user_password'] = 'test123';
$creds['remember'] = true;

$user_verify = wp_signon($creds, true);

wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_auth_cookie($user_verify->data->ID);
wp_set_current_user($user_verify->data->ID);
//fetch the user' site id and redirect to the site.
$user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user($user_verify->data->ID);
if (!empty($user_blogs)) {
    $user_site = array();
    foreach ($user_blogs as $site_id => $site_values) {
        $user_site[] = $site_values->siteurl;
    }

    // Cookies
    setcookie('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $user_site[0]);
    setcookie('COOKIEHASH', md5($user_site[0]));
    setcookie( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );
    setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
    setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user->data->ID , time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS,COOKIEPATH,  COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );

    wp_safe_redirect($siteInfo[0]);
    exit;
}
```

}

Comment: I guess the main cause behind is cookies are not properly set. I dont know if there is any way to set the cookies before redirecting users to their site admin panel

Comment: I believe there is an issue with the SSL cert or Cloudflare if you're using it. please share the site url here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'login_redirect" hook to redirect a user after a successful login
The '/wp-admin' is the url you want th euser to be redirected to, you can edit this as you see fits. 'wp_authenticate' is diffrent from 'login_redirect' as 'login_redirect' is fired after the login is done. Try this out and let me know.

```
   function admin_default_page($redirect_to, $request, $user) {
     
      return '/wp-admin';
    }
    add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page', 10,3);
```